# row affected last

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table with 1 column and more than 100 000 records (rows). More than 1000 users using the table and they updating,inserting,deleting the table.

Is it possible to identify in Oracle to find which row is affected last?

Comment: You can only do this accurately if you have a sequential id column or something like the creation date on each record.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What problem are you trying to solve this way?

Comment: What is the point of a table with one column?  Is this some hypothetical scenario?  make s no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Make a journaling table; for example table_jnl.

Also make a table trigger (after row on insert, update, delete) based on the base table (that is the table which the 1000 users work with).

In the trigger on each insert, update and delete statement you will create a record in the journaling table.

Comment: ...and the 1000 users will be very pleased with the great improvement in performance.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer

```
create table demo(id number)rowdependencies;
Table created.

insert into demo values(1);
COMMIT;
insert into demo values(2);
COMMIT;
insert into demo values(3);
COMMIT;
```

now check

```
select * from (select id,SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN) ts from demo)
where ts=(select max(SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN)) from demo)


ID TS
-- -------------------------------------------
 1 26-OCT-16 09.24.43.000000000 PM
 2 26-OCT-16 09.24.43.000000000 PM
 3 26-OCT-16 09.24.43.000000000 PM
```

Now check update

```
update demo
Set id=0 where id=2;
1 ROW UPDATED

  ID TS
---- -----------------------------------------
   0 26-OCT-16 09.28.15.000000000 PM
```

I am sure this is not a great way but it works if table is created with rowdependencies

Comment: How are you checking for deletes?

Comment: i tried find deleted records but not working but insert and update working fine....i hope this method not able to find deleted record,